# Find most common sub-string pattern in a file

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures, substring

You are given a string like:

```
input_string = """
HIYourName=this is not true
HIYourName=Have a good day
HIYourName=nope
HIYourName=Bye!"""
```

Find the most common sub-string in the file.
Here the answer is "HiYourName=".
Note, the challenging part is that HiYourName= is not a "word" itself in the string
i.e. it is not delimited by spaced around it.

So, just to clarify, this is not most common word problem.

Comment: Aha! Yes, the sub-string should be more than a minimum length, say at-least 6 characters.

Comment: Well then, now we have a programming problem on our hands. Though note that no matter what length of string you give it, the substring returned will be exactly that length, or one of the substrings returned will be. You should plan for that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple brute-force solution:

```
from collections import Counter

s = " HIYourName=this is not true HIYourName=Have a good day HIYourName=nope HIYourName=Bye!"
for n in range(1, len(s)):
    substr_counter = Counter(s[i: i+n] for i in range(len(s) - n))
    phrase, count = substr_counter.most_common(1)[0]
    if count == 1:      # early out for trivial cases
        break
    print 'Size: %3d:  Occurrences: %3d  Phrase: %r' % (n, count, phrase)
```

The output for your sample string is:

```
Size:   1:  Occurrences:  10  Phrase: ' '
Size:   2:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'Na'
Size:   3:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'Nam'
Size:   4:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'ourN'
Size:   5:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'HIYou'
Size:   6:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'IYourN'
Size:   7:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'urName='
Size:   8:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: ' HIYourN'
Size:   9:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: 'HIYourNam'
Size:  10:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: ' HIYourNam'
Size:  11:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: ' HIYourName'
Size:  12:  Occurrences:   4  Phrase: ' HIYourName='
Size:  13:  Occurrences:   2  Phrase: 'e HIYourName='
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build a suffix tree or suffix array out of your string in linear time (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree and links therein) and then after you have built your suffix tree, you can also via depth-first search in linear time compute the number of prefixes of suffixes (number of occurences of a substring) for all longest occuring substrings in linear time, and store this info at each node in the suffix tree. Then, you just need to search the tree to find the maximal number of occurences of a substring (linear time), and then return the substring that is the longest that occurs the maximal number of times (also linear time).

Answer (score 1):

Another brute force without imports:

```
s = """ HIYourName=this is not true HIYourName=Have a good day HIYourName=nope HIYourName=Bye!"""

def conseq_sequences(li):
    seq = []
    maxi = max(s.split(),key=len) # max possible string cannot span across spaces in the string
    for i in range(2, len(maxi)+ 1): # get all substrings from 2 to max possible length
        seq += ["".join(x) for x in (zip(*(li[i:] for i in range(i)))) if " " not in x]
    return max([x  for x in seq if seq.count(x) > 1],key=len) # get longest len string that appears more than once
print conseq_sequences(s)
HIYourName=
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is exactly the same with http://acm.hdu.edu.cn/showproblem.php?pid=2459
the solution is to use suffix array or a suffix tree and use rmq.